# Can Drush make include username, password and settings in one file?

Tags: drush

I hear some talk about Drush make and features.

But not sure how to use them in combination.

Is there a way to have a Drupal site install with ALL settings, including install procedure (enter database name, site name, username ect...)

Include what modules to enable, set user permissions.

I know that Drush can do some of that.

But is it possible to have it ALL done within the drush.make file, can I add standard drush commands to that?

Answer (score 1):

The responsibilities of Drush make involve downloading the files that make up your site.  Site initialization can be done in an installation profile, which is selected at installation time, or perhaps in a script that you run to set up your site.

For Drupal 8, configuration can be imported via the `drush config-import` command.  In Drupal 7, there are many options for managing configuration.  A lot of people (perhaps the majority) use features, but I prefer ctools bonus export.  Here is an [example script](https://github.com/westkingdom/website/blob/master/scripts/install-configuration) I use to set up a test site for behat tests.

If you are just starting out, you might want to consider [using Composer instead of Drush Make](https://pantheon.io/blog/composer-vs-drush-make-which-should-you-use).

Comment: How do I use DrushMake AND Features together? Do I need to export features in the backend via GUI or can I have drush commands that control features?

Comment: Features will create Drupal modules that encapsulate your configuration; you can apply your configuration with the `drush features-revert` command.

Comment: Ok, I can create the Feature via GUI, how to create by Drush and pick options like the "select" boxes from command console?  Additionally, how to enable the module on the destination site with drush? I tried "drush en myfeaturemodule -y" command  but getting errors, enabling through the GUI takes forever, not sure will work at all...times out

Comment: Drupal Stack Exchange is not an interactive tutorial!  I recommend that you read some of the documentation on features, which, you may notice, is not the solution I recommended.  Good luck!